# Password auto change on drupal website

Tags: drupal, passwords

I'm facing new issue with drupal website, when a user create account there is no problem everythings work fine.
But after some time one day or less his password automaticaly change and the system send him reset password email how can I solve this? thank you in advance for you answers.
Cheer.

Comment: No idea about this issue? I really don't understand where the problem come from

Comment: Which version of drupal are u using? are using password_policy or Password Expire module? Does this happen for all users or users with a specific role? Can use see reports page to see if there is some notice there?

Comment: I'm using drupal 6 I'm not using any password policy. 
I made a custom module to autocreate user here is the code don't know if that is the origin of the problem.

Comment: thanks for your help will try to check all your sudgestions then be back for results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal core never resets a user password without interaction from a user.

My best guess it that someone is asking for a new password via /user/password on an account that don't belong to them.

Lets say I have an account called "bratanon" and my friend have one called "foobar".
I can then go to www.yoursite.com/user/password and when the site asks me for "my" username tell the site I am "foobar".

Foobars password will now be changed, and he/she will receive a mail with a link to change it.

Or you have installed a none-core module that does this.

Comment: thank for your answer @BratAnon please try by yourself go to [www.agetix.com](http://www.agetix.com/en) and try register then tomorow try to log in then you'll see I've no custom module that does this. even in rules I've no rule that auto change user password.